# WIX installer for update my program

Tags: c#, wix

installed the program

```
 <Product Id="111" Name="111" Language="1049" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="11" UpgradeCode="111" Codepage="1251">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />
     <DirectoryRef Id="Messages">
      <Component Id="1">
        <File Id="1" Name="1" Source="Messages\1.xml" DiskId="1" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="2">
        <File Id="2" Name="2" Source="Messages\2.xml" DiskId="1" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
```

It is necessary to update the component 2 and add the component 3. Component 1 should not have been updated to be what is now. 
How to implement it with new msi?

Comment: What about when you install this for the first time, do you still need Component 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [Patch](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/patching/wix_patching.html) (if you only wanna include these 'differences' - without comp1) but it will create **.msp** file **not .msi** or [Minor Upgrade](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/upgrades-and-modularization) - to upgrade files here you can set some options to install (but you have to use **msiexec** example:

```
msiexec /i msiname.msi REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vomus
```

Here you can change [REINSTALL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371175(v=vs.85).aspx) and [REINSTALLMODE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371182(v=vs.85).aspx) property.

I would prefer Patch option i gave you link to tutorial, now something from me, to get **.msp** file you need 2 folders, one with old version, and second with new version (both directories with every file), then you have to create installers for these 2 directories - set different paths (it **can't** be same folder, because **you won't be using .msi** files to get differences, but **.wixpdb**!!). Next you get code from tutorial (**patch.wxs** code). In `<PatchFamily>` element you use `<ComponentRef>` element to choose which of components should be checked. If there are some differences - it will be added to **.msp** file.

You can use **Orca.exe** to check what's in **.msp** file. First you have to open installer (without changes) and get form menu *Transform -> View Patch...* And that's it!